# Replacing string column in pandas based on multiple string conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column that contains a list of countries. I basically want to transform it to a new column that says "Inside US" if the row contains either United States or Puerto Rico, otherwise "Outside US".
How can I do this in pandas?

**Expected input:**

```
countries
United States, Japan
China
Brazil, South Africa
Puerto Rico, Spain
United States, Vietnam
Madagascar
```

**Expected output:**

```
countries
Inside US
Outside US
Outside US
Inside US
Inside US
Outside US
```

**My attempt:**
The following code gives me a true or false series which I'm struggling to use..Also not sure if this is the best way to start.

```
df['countries'].str.contains('United States|Puerto Rico')
```

Answer (score 1):

With `np.where` clause:

```
df['country_stat'] = np.where(df['countries'].str
                              .contains('United States|Puerto Rico'), 
                              'Inside US', 'Outside US')
```

---

```
                countries country_stat
0    United States, Japan    Inside US
1                   China   Outside US
2    Brazil, South Africa   Outside US
3      Puerto Rico, Spain    Inside US
4  United States, Vietnam    Inside US
5              Madagascar   Outside US
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's s simple method that'll do it and check the df lines one by one and apply the method.

```
 def check_inside_us(country):
            if country in ['United States', 'Puerto Rico']:
                return 'Inside US'
            else:
                return 'Outside US'
        
        df1['countries'] = df1['countries'].apply(check_inside_us)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).